# Updating RSS-feed with Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, rss

I have a problem with my code. I have one site that publishes open RSS-feed once in a week (inside the same html -link) (link; http://www.sodexo.fi/ruokalistat/rss/weekly_rss/873/fi)

What I need to do is; Get information inside the CDATA in a way, that it automatically updates itself once in a week (everytime it updates it on the linked site).

Im coding with apache cordova, so Im primarily using HTML, JS, CSS and XML.

```
   <rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
              <channel>
                <title>Sodexon ravintolan viikkoruokalista: SeAMK Frami</title>
                <description>Sodexo-ravintolan viikkoruokalista</description>
                <link>http://www.sodexo.fi/</link>
                <language>fi</language>
                <copyright>Sodexo</copyright>
                <pubDate>Mon, 15 May 2017 12:00:00 +0300</pubDate>
                <lastBuildDate>Mon, 15 May 2017 12:00:00 +0300</lastBuildDate>
                <generator>sxomenuoutput</generator>
                <ttl>60</ttl>
                <atom:link href="http://www.sodexo.fi/ruokalistat/rss/weekly_rss/873/fi" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
                <item>
                  <title> Title </title>
                  <description>

        <![CDATA[Content goes here]]>

                  </description>
                  <link>http://www.sodexo.fi/frami</link>
                  <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.sodexo.fi/frami/1494795600</guid>
                  <pubDate>Mon, 15 May 2017 12:00:00 +0300</pubDate>
                  <source url="http://www.sodexo.fi/">Sodexo.fi</source>
                </item>
              </channel>
             </rss>
```

Thank you in advance.